# Postgres ODBC Drive scripted Install

Tags: postgresql, dll, installation, odbc, dllregistration

I am trying to script an install for the [Postgres ODBC Driver](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/) as part of my application's installer. PG gives a great msi but I don't want it to pop up as part of my install. All they say about using the dll's is "Only use this distribution if you know what you are doing!" Unfortunately I cannot find anything showing someone how to do it if they do not know what they are doing.

I have found [a bit of info](http://psqlodbc.projects.pgfoundry.org/faq.html#6.8) about adding  a few reg keys to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI . I am hesitant to use this because the keys do not exist on my computer. I used the msi install. And that the document is from 2010.

So if anyone knows "what they are doing" regarding an odbc driver install I would very much appreciate your guidance.

I'm installing on windows xp. I've got a vm set up so I can start from scratch after each try so I don't need to worry about what failed attempts might be cluttering up. I need the installer to work on xp up through windows 8 so if any one knows of any pitfalls that would not allow for a single isntaller please let me know. I plan to use the 32 bit driver for all installations for now.
I have tried using regsvr32. That didn't work.

content of psqlodbc: 
libeay32.dll
libiconv-2.dll
libintl-8.dll
libpq.dll
pgenlist.dll
pgenlista.dll
pgxalib.dll
psqlodbc30a.dll
psqlodbc35w.dll
ssleay32.dll

Comment: I've had a bit of susses. I ran the psqlODBC msi on a clean xp install and exported [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC] to file. On a second clean xp install I copied the dll's from the pg dll download to the path in the registry and ran the regfile I created on the first computer. This worked. I'm waiting to get a clean windows 7 box to test it on. I would also like to clean up the reg file so that it only has the minimum needed.

Comment: I also found out why I could not find the reg entry on my win7 pc. It's under  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC]. When I get a test win 7 box I'll try out the 64 bit. As I said in the previous comment. I have not tested any win7

Answer (score 2):

Use the stand-alone MSI installers [from the psqlodbc download directory](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) rather than trying to do the install yourself.

It's easier than using the EnterpriseDB installer to install just psqlODBC.

```
msiexec /i the_driver.msi /qn /quiet
```

will do a silent install without displaying any user interface.

Comment: Thanks for trying but as I stated in my question I need this to be part of my application install. You know, Customer downloads the install package for my product and double clicks and all my application dependencies are installed. Not Go here and download this other package and make sure you downloaded the one that is compatible from 3 years ago and then install my software... This is for windows users like my grandmother to use... not some obscure Linux package.

Comment: @RonH Er... MSIs are *designed* to be bundled in other installers. See [`msiexec.exe` and its silent mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx). Duplicating the work of the existing installer makes no sense when you can just bundle it. Do you unpack the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime installer to get the DLLs and install them directly too? (If you do, *oh god please stop*).